# How do I transverse a 2D array given an int top, bottom, left, and right?

Tags: java, algorithm, class, oop

I'm given a public class called FloorPlan and there's a `private int[][] room`, a simple 2D Array with filled with zeroes.
I'm supposed to make a method called

```
private boolean isEmptyRegion(int top, int bottom, int left, int right)
```

where it returns `true` if the rectangular region between the top & bottom and between the left & right including the borders are only zeroes; and will return `false` otherwise. I'm given that `top <= bottom` and `left <= right`, as well as the region overall will be within the limits of room.

Can anybody help me construct the for-loop to go through the borders of the 2D array and the dimensions I am given?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @NiklasB. Question has been answered, and I was really going to edit my post and refer back to you, but thank you anyway! ^^

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to only iterate over those x-values that fall into that rectangular region, and only those y-values that fall into it well. You can do this with:

```
for(int i = top; i <= bottom; i++){
    for(int j = left; j <= right; j++){
        // checking logic here.
    }
}
```

Comment: @あしンたいりン Not a problem!